# aChartEngine works real slow with large data

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I'm working on achartengine (achartengine-1.0.0) in android app, it works fine with small data like <= 600, but when I draw points about **2000+** ( **will use about 8000 or more**), graph gets real slow!! even if user waits for delay but when touches it and moves the graph, graph takes quite long again!

How can I get rid of this slowness?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.1.0 version has a set of performance improvements included. You can download this version [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Most of the time is spent on rendering, so this is where you can improve things:

- Disable antialiasing `mRenderer.setAntialiasing(false);`
- Don't use `PointStyle`s

Other suggestions:

- Add only data that is to be displayed into the model. How does a chart with 2000 points look like?

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I don't see any time difference! almost same as achartengine_1.0

Comment: nRenderer.setAntialiasing does some job but... plus I'm gonna follow your other suggestion to limit the number of points to be rendered.. and I'll accept it as an answer :) thanks for you time and help

Comment: I'm having the same issue with over 11k points. I'll give Dan's suggestion a try, although I already tried setting the antialiasing to false and the performance improvement was minimal.

Comment: OK, I just tried version 506 of ACE with over 11k points. I set the redenrer's antialiasing to false, and I removed the series line width and stroke settings. I have to say that this is a major improvement and it works much better. It is at least responsive with some minor lag.

Answer (score 0):

As Leco mentioned in the comments above, removing setLineWidth() or setting it to a lower value did improve the performance a lot.

Comment: This is not an answer, but should be a comment under the original answer.

Comment: Well I can't seem to comment on the confirmed answer.